# Cuando un div ID este vacio me devuelva un texto

Tags: javascript

Buenas estoy haciendo una programación en JavaScript. Es una especie de carrito donde voy añadiendo productos. Bien, cuando abro este carrito me sale que no tengo nada seleccionado y en cuanto selecciono algo eso se borra y se pone el producto, pero si vacio el carrito me sale vacio, he intento que me vuelva a salir ese mensaje.

**Aquí el codigo**

```
var total = 0;

  //elige contenedor

var miListaDeConceptos = [
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 20 pies", "precio": 20000, "Metros": "50" },
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 40 pies", "precio": 30000, "Metros": "100 "}
    ];


  if($("#div_")){
  function pintaContenedor(x, el ){
  document.getElementById('nadaSeleccionado').style.display='none';
  //Valido si esta activado o no
  let ternariaVal=($(x).is(':checked')?functionPoner(x,el):functionQuitar(x,el));
  }
  function functionQuitar(x,el){

    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    let elegido='#div_'+el;
    total=total- elemento.precio;
    $( elegido).remove();
    mostrarTotal();
  }
  function functionPoner(x,el){
    var miPrecio = elemento
    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    $( "#ContenedorElegido" ).append('<div id="div_'+el+'" class="col-12 listado" data-id="" data-precio="'+elemento.precio+'">'+elemento.concepto+'<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.precio+'€</span><div>Metros:<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.Metros+'m<sup>2</sup></span></div></div>' );
    total += elemento.precio;
    mostrarTotal();
  }

  }else {
    var elementosExistentes = $('#ContenedorElegido .servicio-pres2').length;
    if( elementosExistentes == 0 ){
    // Si cumple con la condición pintas de nuevo el div que dice "No seleccionaste ningún producto"
    $( "#nadaSeleccionado" ).css( "display", "block" );

    console.log(elementosExistentes);
    }
  }
```

Como podeis ver cuando `pintoContenedor` se desactiva `nadaseleccionado` pero cuando se vacia no.

También puse esto para que me saque lo que trae `elementosExistentes` pero no me saca nada.

```
console.log(elementosExistentes);
```

**Con esto activo `pintacontenedor`**

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="20pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,0);" />
     <label for="20pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
     <h4>Módulo de 20 pies</h4>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="cocina=[]" id="40pies" onchange="pintaContenedor(this,1);" />
     <label for="40pies" class="corrigeImgContenedor2"><img src="images/svg/20pies.png" alt="" class="img-fluid corrigeImgContenedor"></label>
      <h4>Módulo de 40 pies</h4>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

**Aquí muestro el div vacio y el de si se llena**

```
<div id="nadaSeleccionado" class="">
    Elige un tipo de contenedor
</div>
<div id="ContenedorElegido" class="servicio-pres2"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner algo de HTML para reproducir el problema? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

He probado de la siguiente manera y me funciona, pero no se si es correcto ya que no entiendo mucho `JavaScript`.
Lo que he hecho es `function pintaContenedor` coja todo el código y luego al final le he añadido un `if`, me sale correcto pero no se si esta bien. Además estos datos que se llenan luego tengo que utilizarlos y no se si es correcto lo que hago.

Sobre todo tengo dudas de que esto este bien:
Alguna opinión??

```
var elementosExistentes = $("#ContenedorElegido .servicio-pres2").length;
```

**Aquí el código**

```
var total = 0;

  //elige contenedor

var miListaDeConceptos = [
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 20 pies", "precio": 20000, "Metros": "50" },
    { "concepto": "Contenedor 40 pies", "precio": 30000, "Metros": "100 "}
    ];

  function pintaContenedor(x, el ){

  $( "#nadaSeleccionado" ).css( "display", "none" );
  //Valido si esta activado o no
  let ternariaVal=($(x).is(':checked')?functionPoner(x,el):functionQuitar(x,el));


  function functionQuitar(x,el){

    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    let elegido='#'+el;
    total=total- elemento.precio;
    $( elegido).remove();
    mostrarTotal();
  }

  function functionPoner(x,el){
    var miPrecio = elemento
    var elemento = miListaDeConceptos[ el ];
    $( "#ContenedorElegido" ).append('<div id="'+el+'" class="col-12 listado" data-id="" data-precio="'+elemento.precio+'">'+elemento.concepto+'<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.precio+'€</span><div>Metros:<span class="pull-right">'+elemento.Metros+'m<sup>2</sup></span></div></div>' );
    total += elemento.precio;
    mostrarTotal();
  }

  if($('#ContenedorElegido').html()) {
    console.log('Si hay contenido');

  }else {
    var elementosExistentes = $("#ContenedorElegido .servicio-pres2").length;
    if( elementosExistentes == 0 ){
    // Si cumple con la condición pintas de nuevo el div que dice "No seleccionaste ningún producto"
    $( "#nadaSeleccionado" ).css( "display", "block" );

    var contenido = $("#ContenedorElegido").html();
    console.log(contenido);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: lo que pasa, que si quiero poner abajo del todo, todas las `var` para trabajar con ellas ya no me las detecta.